# How to enable module in Orchard migration?

Tags: module, migration, orchardcms, taxonomy

I want to enable a specific module in a migration but the module is not enabled immediately.

The issue here seems to be the state of the module, it is set to `Rising` in table `Orchard_Settings_ShellFeatureStateRecord`. In this case I cannot enable the module manually in Admin anymore, I need to restart the web server after the migration has been executed to get the module to state `Up`.

The migration code looks like

```
public class Migration: Orchard.Data.Migration.DataMigrationImpl
{
  // public
    public Migration(Orchard.Environment.Features.IFeatureManager aFeatureManager)
    {
      mFeatureManager = aFeatureManager;
    }

    ...

    public int UpdateFrom1()
    {
      System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, Orchard.Environment.Extensions.Models.FeatureDescriptor> lFeatures =
        mFeatureManager.GetAvailableFeatures().ToDictionary(m => m.Id, m => m);

      if (lFeatures.ContainsKey("Orchard.Taxonomies"))
        mFeatureManager.EnableFeatures(new string[] {"Orchard.Taxonomies"}, true);

      ...
    }

  // private
    private readonly Orchard.Environment.Features.IFeatureManager mFeatureManager;
}
```

I also tried using `IModuleManager`, did not work. Then I tried enabling another simple feature like `Orchard.Alias.UI`, did not work either.

Is this intended behavior or what might be wrong in the code?

Comment: Modules are not supposed to mess with one another, and it seems to me like enabling a module should be the site admin's decision. What's the scenario that justifies it?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy After the dots there is a line of code that adds a taxonomy field to a part and when the taxonomy feature is not enabled then nothing is displayed by the part editor. Therefore I thought enabling the feature would be a good idea since the part is linked to a feature which itself is marked with a dependency to Orchard.Taxonomies in the Module.txt.

Comment: If your feature has a dependency on taxonomies, enabling it will also enable taxonomies. You don't need to do anything else. That is, unless the dependency is something new that you're adding with the new version. In that case, I'd probably display a warning asking the user to enable it, and I'd make the code resilient to taxonomies not being enabled (which is a good idea no matter what).

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy Yes you are right, i have already chosen the warning approach. But i didn't know that dependencies are enabled automatically, thx for the hint. Please post your comment as answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your feature has a dependency on taxonomies, enabling it will also enable taxonomies. You don't need to do anything else. That is, unless the dependency is something new that you're adding with the new version. In that case, I'd probably display a warning asking the user to enable it, and I'd make the code resilient to taxonomies not being enabled (which is a good idea no matter what)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
mFeatureManager.EnableFeatures(new string[] {"Orchard.Taxonomies"},true);
```

to this one:

```
mFeatureManager.EnableFeatures(new string[] {"Orchard.Taxonomies"});
```